# Removing clipping masks from exported PDFs

Tags: graphics, export, pdf-format

I usually export graphics from Mathematica as PDFs which I tweak with Adobe Illustrator. When most plots are exported from Mathematica as PDFs they contain a large number of mostly useless clipping masks.

See:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphic]

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3730003/pi.pdf

All the clipping masks can be removed from this PDF with no effect on the look of the plot.

Is there a way to have the PDF exported without clipping masks or somehow remove them automatically after export, ideally with *Mathematica*?

Note: in some cases (see below) the clipping masks are needed but I don't need a smart solution, if I can get it of all the clipping masks, useless and useful thats fine.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, All}]
```

Comment: Do you see the masks when opening the doc with other programs?

Comment: @belisarius It's a feature of the PDFs, it should be visible in any decent vector editor that supports PDF.

Comment: I would try re-processing the PDFs with various programs (xpdf? ghostscript?) and see if that reomoves the masks.  I know the problem well, but I haven't tried to come up with an automated solution yet.

Comment: @Szabolcs define "decent" :)

Comment: Once upon a time I fixed some EPS bounding box issues by stringbased postprocessing of Mathematica output. Are the masks easily identified in a PDF?

Comment: @Szabolcs, I just tried opening and saving in xpdf (https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3730003/pi-xpdf.pdf), no effect.

Comment: @YvesKlett Many of the masks can be easily selected in Adobe Illustrator by going Select->Objects->Clipping Masks, however, even this doesn't get all of them. I'm not sure of the exact format of the PDF so I don't know how the masks are defined.

Comment: @Szabolcs, ghostscipt seems to improve the situation a little bit, doesn't get of the problem all together though. I did: gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile=pi-gs.pdf pi.pdf

Comment: Actually I was hoping some program would allow do to something which is equivalent to printing.  Printing to PDF might remove it, but I'm not sure how to automate it.

Comment: Ah, I just tried using Preview on OS X and then using the OS X printer thing to save as PDF, didn't work: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3730003/pi-printed.pdf

Comment: Here is the ghostscript file in case someone is interested: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3730003/pi-gs.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to export to eps first and then convert to pdf, try if this works for you. I think it does for me. It is a pretty dirty hack though, so there might be side effects I haven't noticed.

```
p=Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];
Export["plot.eps",StringReplace[ExportString[p,"EPS"],"clip np"->""],"String"]
```

Also, it might not work for all plots.

**Edit**

Actually there is a pretty obvious side effect in form of a colored border around the actual curve. I think with a little more tinkering one might be able to get rid of that too.

**Edit 2**

Alexey Popkov pointed out that it's better to export as "String" than as "Text". I haven't tested it, I just trust him here.

Comment: It is more correct to `Export` as `"String"` the output of `ExportString`, because exporting as `"Text"` potentially can damage the output.