# Text fields in PDF Export

Tags: export, pdf-format, external-calls, postprocessing

I am trying to implement a way in *Mathematica* to export graphics to PDF and then use Inkscape from within *Mathematica* to post process the resulting output with the [pdf-latex export option in Inkscape](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/LaTeX#How_to_turn_an_Inkscape_drawing_into_an_editable_LaTeX_document). In this way, one can have a nice figure made in *Mathematica*, with labels generated by your latex file.

I have managed to get this working almost with the following code:

```
Module[{fig, str = NotebookDirectory[]},
 fig = Plot[Cos[2 x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesLabel -> {"$x$", "$\\cos{2x}$"}];
 Export[str <> "in.pdf", fig];
 RunProcess[{"inkscape", "-z", "-D",
  "--file=" <> str <> "in.pdf", "--export-pdf=" <> str <> "out.pdf","--export-latex"},
  ProcessEnvironment -> Association[DeleteCases[GetEnvironment[All], "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" -> _]]];
]
```

Incidentally, this was a major pain in itself because [*Mathematica* changes the PATH variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88062/12908).

Unfortunately, this still does not work because for some reason *Mathematica* creates individual text fields for every part of a string that is separated by a space or some funny symbol. In any case, in the example above the x-axis label is processed fine, but the y-axis label is separated in *five* different text fields:

`"$\cos", "{", "2x", "}", "$"`

In this example, I could have given `$\\cos\\,2x$` as the y-axis label instead, and this would have worked, but for more complicated formula this fix does not work and the .tex file that is created by Inkscape is worthless. Moreover, any negative number on the ticks is also broken in this way because the minus sign is split off from the magnitude.

I have also tried exporting as a .svg file but that does not work at all, because *Mathematica* includes text as a graphic in the .svg file.

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and my *Mathematica* version is 10.4.1.0

**Question:**

Is there a way to force *Mathematica* to export a pdf in such a way that strings are included as a single text field in the pdf?

Comment: Seems like a similar question as https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42274/49861

Comment: Matex package might be relevant.  This is the homepage of the package http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html There are many posts devoted to the package here.